# how to add multiple vertical lines in a lattice panel?

Tags: r, lattice

Consider this example

```
library(lubridate)
library(tibble)
library(lattice)

dat <- tibble(mydate = c(ymd('2018-02-01'),
                  ymd('2018-02-02'),
                  ymd('2018-02-03'),
                  ymd('2018-02-04'),
                  ymd('2018-02-05')),
       myx = c(1,2,3,4,5),
       myz = c(2,3,2,3,1))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  mydate       myx   myz
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 2018-02-01     1     2
2 2018-02-02     2     3
3 2018-02-03     3     2
4 2018-02-04     4     3
5 2018-02-05     5     1
```

I know I can easily plot the two time series using `xyplot`

```
dat %>% xyplot(myx + myz ~ mydate, outer = TRUE, data = ., type = 'l',
               layout = c(1,2))
```

[image]

My problem is that I have another `tibble` that contains dates of interest and I would like to plot vertical lines in the chart above for these dates.

```
events <- tibble(mydate = c(ymd('2018-02-03'),
                            ymd('2018-02-05')))
```

How can I do that easily?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) panel function** Use a panel function like this:

```
xyplot(myx + myz ~ mydate, dat, outer = TRUE, type = "l", layout = 1:2, 
  panel = function(...) {
    panel.xyplot(...)
    panel.abline(v = events$mydate)
  })
```

**2) layer** or use layer in latticeExtra:

```
library(latticeExtra)

xyplot(myx + myz ~ mydate, dat, outer = TRUE, type = "l", layout = 1:2) +
  layer(panel.abline(v = mydate), data = events)
```

**2a) xyplot.zoo** Note that this can be simplified slightly using zoo:

```
library(latticeExtra)
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(dat)
xyplot(z) + layer(panel.abline(v = mydate), data = events)
```

### Note

To add just the first vertical line to the first panel and the second vertical line to the second panel:

```
xyplot(z) +
  layer(panel.abline(v = mydate[1]), data = events, packets = 1) +
  layer(panel.abline(v = mydate[2]), data = events, packets = 2)
```

or

```
vline <- function(i) {
  layer(panel.abline(v = events$mydate[i]), data = list(i = i), packets = i)
}
Reduce("+", init = xyplot(z), lapply(1:2, vline))
```

Comment: amazing. pretty good stuff. this `lattice` package is so much better than `ggplot` for time series

Comment: Just as a follow up, if there a simple way to modify your code such that only the first date would appear on the first chart, and only the second date would appear on the second? I am struggling a bit... Thanks!

Comment: no, the first vertical line in panel one, the second vertical line in panel two. thanks!

Comment: good stuff... this layer thing id much better than the horrible panel syntax in base lattice... thanks!

Comment: Have transferred comments to the Note at the end of the answer.